# UITextField in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, autolayout

I'm trying to add a UITextField to the right of a UINavigationBar with this code:

```
UITextField *txtField=[[UITextField alloc]init];
txtField.text=@"Text Goes Here";


txtField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:txtField];



NSArray * constraints=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[txtField(100)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(txtField)];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addConstraints:constraints];
```

It happens that the program crashes saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

And I can't figure out why...
What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using a custom class for the UINavigationBar?

Comment: Instead of adding a text field to the navigation bar, try adding a UIBarButtonItem to the controller's navigationItem property. Use initWithCustomView: to make your bar button item, and pass the text field as the custom view.

Comment: No I'm using UINavigationBar not any kind of subclass

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your textfield as a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view, and setting that as a the `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`:

```
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
txtField.text = @"Text Goes Here";
txtField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:txtField];

self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea but for some reason mine wasn't showing, so I followed the code at this link and it started working: http://www.iphonegamezone.net/118/